# Verify merchant account with bank account in different country

Tags: android, merchant-account

As I noticed I did not receive further payments from Google until I dont verify myself. I am a sole traider, so I will have to send them an ID and an invoice. 
I share a flat in Austria and have a bank account there which I have used for receiving my android payments in the last 1.5 years. But I am not an austrian citizen, just sometimes I go there. My own country is not supported to sell paid apps, so my question: will they have a problem at the verification if I send them my not austrian ID and an austrian invoice?

Another sentence I intend to emphasize from a Google page (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/150324?hl=en): "*If you are not located in any of the countries listed above, **or** do not own the required bank account for receiving payments, Google may not be able to pay for the sales in that account by any other means.*" --- For me it means I "only" have to own a required bank account but I am not sure if I strictly have to live and be a citizen in that country.

My invoice will arrive soon, i could wait but it is very worrisome for me. 
This would cause me a huge problem since I sell lots of android apps every day generating siginificant revenue. But I wonder if there was no problem so far, why would it be now?

Thank you very much for the answers in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about contract details

Comment: I am sorry to hear this, but I was browsing the internet for hours and did not find any clues to this question.

Comment: @JaniBela: I know this question has been closed as off-topic, but I would **really** appreciate if you shared how you solved this - I am in a very similar situation. Is it possible to use Austrian bank account if you are not located in one of the supported countries?

Comment: @johndodo Did you solve this issue yet? Did you use Austrian bank as a foreign citizen?

Comment: @Orangutan Sorry, no... I had a few options (opening a foreign company) so I knew it was "solveable", but project never made it that far. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume that if you have a valid bank account in Austria that Google can verify it shouldn't be a problem. Citizenship shouldn't matter as long as your not from a barred country, http://doresearch.stanford.edu/research-scholarship/export-controls/export-controlled-or-embargoed-countries-entities-and-persons#countries

An alternative would be to open an American Bank account by getting an iTin number from the IRS (Individual Taxpayer Identification Number ) http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Obtaining-an-ITIN-from-Abroad and then just have google deposit the money there.

I am a Canadian Citizen, and use a Wells Fargo account in the states via this.

Comment: I am from Europe, and I am not aware of this American bank account at all. Do you mean - if google refuses my verification - I can open an american bank account from Europe and have them transfer the money there? It seems pretty complicated to me, not to mention how I will able to get to the money?

Comment: Wells Fargo, although I know they are not the only one, is accessible via any Europe based ATM, (Maestro and Cirrus) they just snail mail you the card.

Comment: UPDATE: Since the Patriot Act Wells Fargo requires you to physically come in to verify your identity, this isn't to much of a problem for me since I go there every couple of years anyway, but if your reading this post since it was first published, you should be aware of this.